# get page number in object of laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have object given below and i wanted to pagination in this how can i get

```
$productListArray = array();
 $productListObject = ((object)[
                "id"=>$productList->id, 
                "title"=>$productList->title,
                "slug"=>$productList->slug,
                'categoryName'=>$categoryName[0]->cat_title,
                'brand'=>$brandName[0]->brandname,
                'minMrp'=>$minMrp,
                'maxMrp' =>$maxMrp,
                'minSellingPrice' => $minSellingPrice,
                'maxSellingPrice' => $maxSellingPrice,
                'rating'=>$productList->rating,
                'rating_count' => $productList->rating_count,
                'image' => $img[0]
            ])->paginate();
       array_push($productListArray, $productListObject);
    }
    return response()->json($productListArray, 200);
```

Comment: Hm, `$productListObject` is a single object, what are you trying to paginate there?

Comment: thanks for your responce i have trying to get page number when its giving responce ``

Comment: Page number of what?

Comment: `[
    {
        "id": 164,
        "title": "ELEGANT SUIT",
        "slug": "elegant-suit",
        "categoryName": "Unstitched Suits",
        "brand": "SR SUITS",
        "minMrp": "2800",
        "maxMrp": "2800",
        "minSellingPrice": "2400",
        "maxSellingPrice": "2400",
        "rating": "0",
        "rating_count": "0",
        "image": "329791604493274.jpeg"
    }
]`

Comment: here its output in this showing in this i wanted to get page number like `paginate() ` giving in laravel

Comment: why you are pushing the object in array  pass the "productListObject " collection to response

Comment: `{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
      {
        "minSellingPrice": "2400",
        "maxSellingPrice": "2400",
        "rating": "0",
        "rating_count": "0",
        "image": "329791604493274.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?page=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products",
    "per_page": 15,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 3,
    "total": 3
}`

Comment: i wanted to response like this when its returning responce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your support i found solution,
first add on your header

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection; 
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

then make an other function

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

after than call this function where you want in class

```
$data = $this->paginate($productListArray);
    return response()->json($data, 200);
```

last 2 lines already mentioned in my questions
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get the Current page using laravel paginator `Paginator::currentPageResolver`

```
public function index()
{
    $currentPage = 3; // You can set this to any page you want to paginate to

    // Make sure that you call the static method currentPageResolver()
    // before querying users
    Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($currentPage) {
        return $currentPage;
    });

    $users = \App\User::paginate(5);

    return view('user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: it's showing Call to undefined method Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver() in file

Comment: `{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "minSellingPrice": "2400",
      "maxSellingPrice": "2400",
      "rating": "0",
      "rating_count": "0",
      "image": "329791604493274.jpeg"
    }
  ]"first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products?page=1",
  "next_page_url": null,
  "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products",
  "per_page": 15,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 3,
  "total": 3
}`

Comment: i wanted to responce like this when its returning responce